# Are there options to modify the task manager for Android's new update Lollipop?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, samsung-galaxy-s-5, task-management

I have a Samsung Galaxy S5, and for the past few months I have held back on getting the Lollipop update. One of the big reasons why was because of this- not being able to go to the home screen through the task switcher button.
(by pressing on something other than the apps in the navigation window)
 I finally got it today, but I just want to know if it's possible to do this in the Lollipop update, because I used it frequently in the Kit Kat OS. I want to be able to navigate between apps and the home screen without having to ex-out all my apps or repeatedly press the home button.

Thank You for your time.

Comment: I'm not understanding your request. Are you saying that previously, when you tapped the recents button to display the recent applications, if you then tapped on a part of the screen that wasn't an app, it would take you to the home screen? And now, in Lollipop, it doesn't do that? If I'm correct, why is it that you don't wish to simply press the Home button to go home? And it shouldn't require multiple presses, unless there's something I'm unclear about.

Comment: @TurboFool I guess he means that he has to minimize all apps to be able to switch to another one and not see the running app through the background of the task manager. I guess it's not possible to change that without massive effort on a custom rom.

Comment: @TurboFool Yes, that's exactly what I mean. The reason I don't just press the home button is because I don't want to press it again and again (don't want to break it from overuse), and I got used to doing it that way. If it's not possible, I'll just have to accept it, but I first wanted to ask if I can change it, maybe through an app or manually configuring it through the computer or something.

Comment: Btw, I know that there's an assistant menu that allows you to go home through it (like the iPhone's button-on-screen-thing) but I wanna know if I can do it through the task manager.

Comment: I don't believe it's possible. And the phone was designed for you to hit the home button over and over. If it can't withstand that, it should never have gotten past product testing. Honestly, the feature you were relying on is likely to be VERY problematic and jarring to users. If they tap wrong, they're taken to an entirely different place. I would imagine there were complaints, and that's why it was removed.

Comment: @TurboFool Okay, thanks. I'll get used to it, and they updated the assistant menu so I'm thinking of using that. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Forgive my late tuning in (oh, just 1h late), but there are [several apps allowing you to re-assing keys](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_settings#group_546). E.g. [Button Saviour](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smart.swkey), which emulates soft-keys (but requires root). Maybe one of those can help you out?

Comment: @Izzy Thanks for the suggestions (I checked all in the Edit Keys Section) but none have really worked for me. (I also don't have root) The website seems to have a lot of stuff though so I'll check back if I need anything else. Thank you again 

Comment: Anytime, @TimBob – was worth a try. And yes, lots of stuff hopefully well organized (and kept up-to-date). Be welcome to the articles section as well! I've actually set it up to support Android.SE, amongst others, for cases like this ;)

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out you can't edit task manager behaviors. The option to go to the home screen through the task manager has been removed, probably because it hindered users switching between apps, which must be why the switching app windows are are considerably larger in Lollipop.